# Any sample for iCloud?

Tags: sample, ios5, icloud

iCloud is coming to us.

As iOS developer, after reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/installation/), I just wonder if there are any samples for this new tech. Thanks

Comment: Please ask over at https://devforums.apple.com/. This question is only relevant while iCloud is pre-release, so it is too localized to be appropriate for StackOverflow. Plus, check the NDA you agreed to with Apple.

Comment: Have a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795629/icloud-basics-local-app-sandbox-vs-cloud-sandbox-on-device

Comment: Take a look at - http://icloudintegration.blogspot.com/

Comment: Check this tutorial walkthrough app. There are some explanations on how iCloud behaves as well. http://github.com/lichtschlag/iCloudPlayground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the beta Xcode and check in the docs (after downloading them) for "What's new", there's an overview there.

Answer (score 1):

visit this blog you may get some basic thing about iCloud storage
 http://icloudintegration.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

Adding few more links which I found very useful.

iCloud with Core-data - http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/452

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1 and
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6031/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2