# iCloud Document hardly sync after first launch

Tags: objective-c, icloud, uidocument

I'm using UIDocument method to store data in iCloud.

So I have 2 devices to test, when I first launch the app on iPhone, then I do some changes then call **saveToURL:completionHandler**, after that I launch the app on iPad, it's working good, at least it does retrieve the data from Cloud server.

My problem arise after both have their local Cloud storage. Now I made some changes on iPad, then I switch back to iPhone, I noticed the iPhone still having its old data, not the changes that iPad did earlier.

Does anyone know what's the problems? I even try to turn on/off Document & Data in iCloud setting then re-run the app but no luck, it's still doesn't working.

Comment: isn't this a duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227457/when-does-ios-icloud-sync-to-the-server

Try reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8379092/611055

Comment: I've deleted the previous question.
Thanks for reply :)

Comment: I try to follow this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851039/how-to-use-icloud-to-store-and-sync-app-files/8379092#8379092
It works only for the first time after I've implemented the "move file to Cloud and download file from Cloud"
After that I try again then back to same the problem where the other device doesn't update the latest save file from Cloud.
I'm not sure is SAVE part cause problem or the LOAD part. Someone please help