# when and how to detect an iCloud conflict?

Tags: iphone, conflict, icloud

I use iCloud to sync an user xml file between devices in my apps, with a UIDocument subclass, similar to the code from the question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795629/icloud-basics-and-code-sample. but I am not sure when and how should I detect a conflict. I read the sdk doc and searched  the internet but didn't seem to find any information with detailed information. it seems we can use some code like
                NSNumber* conflicted ;
                [url getResourceValue:&conflicted forKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemHasUnresolvedConflictsKey error:nil];

but in my app, it seems always give a true value for "conflicted"?
also I am not sure when should I detect the conflict, my guess is before the contentsForType method of the UIDocument subclass is called. if anyone can give any hint that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should observe the `UIDocumentStateChangedNotification`. If the `documentState` property of your document has the `UIDocumentStateInConflict` flag set, there is a conflict. Note that a document can be in multiple states simultaneously, so don't check with `==`, instead use something like `if (document.state & UIDocumentStateInConflict) {...`.

You can then get the conflicting versions with the `otherVersionsOfItemAtURL:` class method of `NSFileVersion`.

You can find more detailed information in the [chapter on resolving document conflicts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ResolveVersionConflicts/ResolveVersionConflicts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH6-SW1) in the [Document-Based App Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH1-SW1).