# How can we store the data like photos and videos in icloud

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I am working on ios5 new feature (icloud). i have to store my photos and videos in icloud storage.how can i save and retrieve the data from icloud.can anyone suggest me with the useful tutorials.thanks in adavance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution of saving and retrieving our photos into the icloud.
Go through the following 
http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/add-an-icloud-photo-gallery-to-your-app-with-mticloudphotogallery-library/

It gives you the source code for saving and retrieving of your photos.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works fine with photos and videos but I found post in this link with some code that maybe usefull for you :

[iCloud basics: local app sandbox vs. cloud sandbox on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795629/icloud-basics-and-code-sample)