# Is there a way to save game data permanently?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

So when an app gets deleted they can redownload and the data will still be there. I am trying to store some data forever.

Comment: Don't abuse the `xcode` tag - this is not in any way related to the IDE.

Answer (score 5):

You need to store it in the cloud, and have an account system for the user to log in under, so that you would know what data to send back to that client.

You can use [iCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795629/icloud-basics-and-code-sample) from apple, or use a web [service of your own](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/create-nodejs-web-services-in-one-line), or someting like [parse](http://parse.com).

Comment: This answer is very good. Assuming you're using your own web service, I would just like to add that credentials stored in the keychain will persist. You can randomly generate a password for that device and associate it with the data in the cloud. Then you can grab the credential information when the app is reinstalled, and download the data. The user doesn't even have to worry about an account.