# Enable iCloud Functionalities With the Use of an On-Off Switch in An iOS App, or Similar to the Pages.App

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, icloud

I have a fully built Core Data based application in the App Store and with an update I'm working on, I'm bringing iCloud synching capabilities to the app. This is going to be an option for the user to enable instead of having it enabled straight away.

I have a `UITabBarController` and in the 5th tab, I have a settings pane where one of the options will be to turn on or off iCloud synching, through the use of a Switch.

What I'm not sure about is how exactly to enable something like this, because the `SettingsViewController` (5th Tab) needs to essentially talk to the `AppDelegate` to invoke this.

My `persistentStoreCoordinator` in the `AppDelegate` is below:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Lite.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSURL *cloudURL = [self grabCloudPath:@"iCloud"];

    NSDictionary *options = nil;
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"OnLatestVersion"]) {
        options = @{                                       NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                                           NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                                           NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey: cloudURL, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"LiteCloud"};
        NSLog(@"Using iCloud from migration");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Using the other store without the iCloud Migration");
        options = @{                                       NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                                           NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES};
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }


    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

It's not related to this question why the persistentStore is like that, but essentially, I want to ensure that in the SettingsViewController, when the user turns the iCloud switch ON, it invokes the iCloud synching.

I've seen lots of posts relating to the ability to turn off iCloud, but never one that's talked about how to do it, etc.

**Edit: Small Update**

Through a bit of thinking about this, perhaps I can do this:

- Take out storesWill and storesDidChange notifications from the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the AppDelegate and place them into a separate method
- Have a notification listener (custom notification) in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions
- This custom notification would trigger those methods when called
- In the SettingsVC, call the custom notification when iCloud has been enabled in the Switch
- Let it perform the required actions in the AppDelegate

Is this correct? I understand it theoretically, if this is the case, but just not sure how best to implement this.

If that is all correct, would something like the below be suitable for the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults:)
                                             name:@"SomethingChanged"
                                           object:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];
```

How would one go about achieving something like this? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to find out how to manage iCloud, or are you more concerned with how you get the persistent store coordinator in your settings view controller?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom. I'm interested in how I get the persistentStoreCoordinator in my Settings, because I'm happy managing if iCloud is available, etc.. What I'm trying to achieve is essentially if the iCloud switch if flipped on in the SettingsVC, I'd like to contact the App Delegate to say ok, start doing your work.. and I'm guessing the persistentStoreCoordinator is the place to start that. However, I don't have the Notification Handlers for storesWill/DidChange in the PSC of the App Delegate.. I have those handlers in the didFinishLaunching.. so I guess that needs adjusting too?

Comment: I think this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795629/icloud-basics-and-code-sample

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12816/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-3

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. That last post was extremely helpful. 

What I'm confused about is whether to use NSNotification or NSUserDefaults. 

When the user switches from On to Off, should I be using both a NSNotification to listen in the App Delegate, AND a NSUserDefault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an NSUserDefaults key, and then using NSNotification to check for that key should probably work. In the settings view, when the switch is flipped, you change a BOOL value in NSUserDefaults, then you call an NSNotification in the appDelegate to update based on the changed NSUserDefaults value. In applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions like you said you can do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults)
                                         name:@"SomethingChanged"
                                       object:nil];
```

and in reloadFetchedResults you can check for a key in the NSUserDefaults you set in the settings view. In the settings view right after you change the key in NSUserDefaults call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification: @"SomethingChanged"];`

Comment: Thanks so much Eytan - that's absolutely perfect and your thinking worked like an absolutely charm. This was something that shouldn't have been this difficult but I really appreciate your answer here! thanks again