# How to Sync data in sqlite data base data to i-Cloud data base

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, icloud

I am saving images,name,last name in local sqlite data base . I want to same content in sqlite data base save on i-Cloud. I am stuck on this problem please give me solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [iCloud basics and code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795629/icloud-basics-and-code-sample)

Comment: @Matei_Radu this is NOT a duplicate of [iCloud basics and code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795629/icloud-basics-and-code-sample). This question is *specific* to syncing a SQLite database to iCloud, which has its own difficulties, while [iCloud basics and code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795629/icloud-basics-and-code-sample) is about storing document *text* data in the iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sync sqlite database file on iCloud as it will corrupt your database. There are few options for you:

1. Use iCloud sqlite sync via core data
2. Zip sqlite file and sync it with iCloud, then unzip it inside app when needed

Comment: is this a valid answer?